# Objective C, unable to authenticate the user for a POST action

Tags: objective-c, xml, web-services, post

I am trying to send data to a biztalk server using a POST action

I found a very good tutorial on this under this link[enter link description here](http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/making-a-post-in-objective-c-xcode-to-sharepoint-webservice-requiring-windows-ntlm-authenticaton-for-iphone-or-ipad/)

I wrote it exactly the same ( I changed the xml portion of course to reflect my parameters). but the data does not get transmitted , I know for a fact that the server require authentication . What I was expecting is the function `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection` to be called but instead the function

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

gets called. I found that the error message that I get is the following :

```
ERROR: with the connection Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x210f5d70 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<server path>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<server path>, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x210f5290 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}
```

I did some research on the `Code=-1003` is equivalent to `kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost` and I assume that this is related to the fact that the server is behind a firewall that needs authentication.

my question is the following ,assuming that the logic I have is right, is there a way to access the corporate network first with user credentials before doing the POST action ? I think that if I get this fixed things should work

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message suggests that it cannot reach the server at all as opposed to an authentication problem.  Are you able to navigate to that site in Safari from your iPad/Phone?  Do you need to be connected to a VPN to hit the site?

You should get a different error if you have an authentication problem.

Comment: I tried and can t reach this site from safari .Unfortunately VPN is not an option for me.

Comment: If you cannot connect to the server, then this isn't an authentication problem.  You have to be able to access the server in order to download data.

Comment: In other words - this URL needs to be available on the public Internet, or your iOS device will need to be on the internal network, or on a VPN in order for you to access the site and even have a chance to provide credentials.

Comment: I checked with my security team and you are right :) . they gave me a public link instead  , all the functions get called as expected but nothing is transmitted to the server ... can it be a security issue ( I am using https and not http ...)?

Comment: What error are you receiving, and have you confirmed that you are able to access and POST to these URLs from the extranet?

Comment: I am not receiving any error . and yes this is an external access and I can access from anywhere and post on it. I just don t see what I have submitted on the servers ...

Comment: To confirm - you aren't receiving an error message from the server?  Are you sure that your request is reaching the server?  If so, how?  You could try using something like Fiddler to examine the traffic.

Comment: Yes I am not receiving an error from the server . I think yes it is reaching the server because I get an authentication challenge.

Comment: How are you responding to the challenge?  We implement something like the following for our asynchronous connections (had to modify a bit to get under the character limit):

Comment: - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:USERNAME
                                                                    password:PASSWORD
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

Comment: it s almost the same ( I don t have the if statment fot the previousFailureCount but I included it now )

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior you are seeing then, I assume this has diverged from the original question?  What callbacks are hit after you send the credentials?

Comment: I created another Question for this new issues under this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627810/objective-c-unable-create-an-xml-post-action

Comment: I'll respond on the new question.  Did this post answer your original question though?